# Android O can not request permission when pre permission dialog is showing

Tags: android, permissions

I request location and storage permissions when the app starts. I can see 
the location dialog, but if the code requests storage permission when requesting location dialog is showing, the length of permissions and grant results in onRequestPermissionsResult is 0 and I can not see the request storage permissions dialog.

Here is the code:

```
  String [] permissions1 = { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION };
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,permissions1,1);

  TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

     @Override
     public void run() {

       Log.d(LOG_TAG,"request storage permission");
       String [] permissions2 = { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE };

       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,permissions2,2);
     }
  };

  Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.schedule(task, 2000);
```

Comment: why are you using timer task to show the second dialog, You can pass all the requests in one array and the framework will take care of the rest to show dialogs for all the permissions requests

Comment: Because I request permission in defferent class in my app.I use timer tast to  simulate that situation.

Comment: @jakirhussain That's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Request permission when you want it, not in any other activity or fragment. you can use libraries like [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) to simply permission requests

Comment: For example：I need user's location data and storage permission to save something after app started. But when the location permission dialog is showing. I can not get the storage permission and storage permission dialog nerver showed.

Comment: You can pass the array of permission required in a single array and the framework will show dialogs accordingly. Then check for the permission results in `onRequestPermissionsResult`